# Reversing an application of `sym` to `ua` and `isoToEquiv` in cubical type theory

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory, cubical-type-theory

I am proving a kind of structure invariance principle for magmas in Cubical Type Theory with the Agda/Cubical library. This is done by constructing a path between two simple magmas and then transporting proofs of simple properties about this path. I have already obtained most of the proof (see my [code repository](https://github.com/wvhulle/transport-magmas)) but did not manage yet to complete the following lemma.

At some point in the proof I have the following given:

- A bijection between types: `f : ℕ → ℕ₀`
- The isomorphism constructed with `f`: `fIso : Iso ℕ ℕ₀`
- A function that gives the inverse isomorphism of an isomorphism: `invIso : Iso A B → Iso B A`

Now, I would like to prove that:

```
sym (ua (isoToEquiv fIso)) ≡ ua (isoToEquiv (invIso fIso))
```

There are two parts to my question:

- Is this a valid theorem in HoTT? Although this statement seems valid, maybe I have produced a false statement?
- Are there built-in functions in the Agda/Cubical that may help in the proof?

Comment: I got [help](https://github.com/agda/cubical/issues/146) on the Agda/Cubical issue tracker. Apparently, it is better to use equivalence induction. Now, I only have to prove the simplified base case `(λ i → ua (idEquiv A) (~ i)) ≡ ua (invEquiv (idEquiv A))`.

Comment: Since $ua(f^{-1}) = ua(f)^{-1}$ holds (HoTT book, just below UA in Sect 2.10), your statement should hold. Note that $f^{-1}$ is the inverse equivalence, while $ua(f)^{-1}$ is the inverse path. As long as iso inverses are equivalence inverses, everything should be OK. (The part about the built-in functions looks off-topic here, unfortunately -- I don't know much about that library anyway)

Comment: @chi, Thank you! I found that statement in the book as well. To prove it, I switched from isomorphisms to equivalences and used equivalence induction from the Agda Cubical library. I will try to post a full answer to my question below to mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 3):

The original  statement in my question 
`sym (ua (isoToEquiv fIso)) ≡ ua (isoToEquiv (invIso fIso))`
is a valid statement in Homotopy Type Theory but because (homotopy-) isomorphisms are a special case of equivalences, the statement can be generalized to

`sym (ua fEquiv) ≡ (ua (invEquiv fEquiv))` (*)

It is one of the properties of `ua` that are informally proven in the [Univalent Foundations book](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) in section 2.10.

### Solution

The results from [1](https://homotopytypetheory.org/book/) have been implemented and proven in the [lemmas](https://github.com/agda/cubical/pull/147/commits/2ee2e6a665feda43e8cf8a45bd608ba69513963a#diff-c60a156af820603da797f889dbfb965cR174) in the Agda Cubical library. The function `uaInvEquiv` of those lemmas in particular solves my problem (*). For future applications it is better to use [4](https://github.com/agda/cubical/pull/147/commits/2ee2e6a665feda43e8cf8a45bd608ba69513963a#diff-c60a156af820603da797f889dbfb965cR174) because they are more general than my own approach below.

---

### Historical solution

Using the [hint](https://github.com/agda/cubical/issues/146#issuecomment-496145420) to use `EquivJ`, I gave a [proof for the theorem](https://github.com/wvhulle/transport-magmas/blob/master/MagmaPath.agda) that may not be the most efficient one but it worked (typechecked) for my specific case:

```
baseIndLemma : (A : Type ℓ-zero) → (λ i → ua (idEquiv A) (~ i)) ≡ ua (invEquiv (idEquiv A))
baseIndLemma A = 
  sym ( ua (idEquiv A) ) ≡⟨ uaIdEquiv ⟩
  sym refl ≡⟨ refl ⟩
  refl ≡⟨ sym uaIdEquiv ⟩
  ua (idEquiv A) ≡⟨ cong ua (equivEq (idEquiv A) (invEquiv (idEquiv A)) refl) ⟩
  ua (invEquiv (idEquiv A)) ∎

myUaInvEquiv : sym (ua fEquiv) ≡ (ua (invEquiv fEquiv))
myUaInvEquiv = EquivJ
  (λ _ _ e → sym (ua e) ≡ ua (invEquiv e)) (λ A → baseIndLemma A) ℕ₀ ℕ fEquiv
```